# How to set innodb-memcached(used in MySQL 5.6) on MariaDB 10.x?

Tags: memcached, innodb, mariadb

Is it the same as mysql?

```
MariaDB []> install plugin daemon_memcached soname "libmemcached.so";
```

Please help me I'm confused how to set it in MariaDB..

Answer (score 0):

I thought MariaDB can not really support memcached until now, MariaDB 10.0.

There some configuration items related with memcached, but not support yet.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_api_bk_commit_interval